# Show that there exist a basis of $E$ in which $f$ and $g$ are upper-triangular matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $f$ and $g$ be two endomorphisms of a complex vector space $E$ such that $f \circ g = g \circ f $. Show that there exists a basis of $E$ in which $f$ and $g$ are upper-triangular matrices.

The proof is by recurrence.

The result is true for $ n = 1 $.

We suppose that there exists a basis $ B = (e_1,...,e_n) $ in which $f$ and $g$ are upper triangular and we prove this for the case of an $n+1$ dimensional space.

$f$ and $g$ share a common eigenvector $v_\lambda$.

We will have another basis, $ B'= \{v_{\lambda} \} \cup {B} $, in which $f$ and $g$ are:

$ A(f,B') =  
\begin{pmatrix} 
v_\lambda & a \\
0 & A' \end{pmatrix} $

and

$ C(g,B') =  
\begin{pmatrix} 
v_\lambda & b \\
0 & C' \end{pmatrix} $

We have $f \circ g = g \circ f \iff A'C' = C'A'  $.

From the recurrence hypothesis, $A'$ and $C'$ are upper triangular in the basis $B$, thus $A$ and $C$ are upper triangular in the basis $B'$.

I'm not sure if they are upper triangular in the same basis.

Comment: I won't start with a basis $B$ where $f,g$ are both upper-triangular for the simple reason that $f,g$ are defined on an $n+1$ dimensional vector space. Build instead a basis of $E$ starting with $v_{\lambda}$, and notice that $A',C'$ commute and are $n$ dimensional. Now consider a basis $B$ where $A',C'$ are upper-triangular, and you are done.

Comment: @user26857 Thank you so much!